# Fetching Request param in Python Quart

Tags: python, quart

I am trying to convert my flask app to Quart ASGI, facing an issue when try to fetch request param/argument.

It gives an error when normal request is used with Quart

```
Example:
@app.route('/')
async def hello():
    return function(request.args.get('requestID'))
```

Not able to fetch param argument using **request.args.get('requestID')** in Quart

Comment: From the looks of your question I'd say you're confusing 'request header' with 'request argument' or 'request parameter'. Take a look at the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) on request headers. Alternatively take a look at this curl invocation: `curl -v -H "Accept: text/html" http://localhost:5000?requestID=1`. It passes the request header `Accept` and the request parameter `requestID`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, edited the context.

Comment: Are you certain the error is not with the `object.function` usage? I've not seen this before in Python. Could you add the actual error that is raised to your question?

Comment: Yea you are right, there is no such thing as Object.function, that function was part of a class so i kept in that terms, sorry to confuse. So the error message i was getting is "RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem."